# 98 Chevy S10 not starting

Tags: starting, chevrolet, s10

98 Chevy S10 tries to turn over then it dies , new battery and had it tested , head lights dim when trying to start, could not get it started with jumper cables but when hooked directly to fuse box it fires right up but then will not start again once turned off any ideas could it still be starter and why will it not start at battery with jumpers

Comment: One fuse defective?

Comment: You said you were hooking the jumpers up the the fuse box. Where are you hooking the black jumper cable? Directly to the frame? This just sounds like bad battery terminal(s) and/or the wire coming of the battery.

Comment: Definitely sounds like bad terminals like Jeffyx said. I have found  bad terminals to be number one cause with engine no start I find it about %90 percent of the time